# How to use external scoped scss in Vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm building a project on `Vue-nuxt`. I want to use external `SCSS` scoped to only that component.

```js
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <h3>{{ heading }}</h3>
        <p>{{ para }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    import './../assets/css/card.scss'
    
    export default {
      props: {
        heading: String,
        para: String
      }
    }
</script>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import your scss files in style tags and assign scoped to it. Like below:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "sample.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: you can't import inside style tag?

Comment: of course you can. Its the place to write scss code and import scss files

Comment: @anny123 https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/604#issuecomment-287620657 looks like you can import in the style tag. Does it not work for you?

Comment: @Tanner ^Above comment

Comment: @import for css/scss within the style tags

Comment: I had this issue where I wanted to import a scss style but it wasn't working: the problem was I was adding some dynamic html via string for a certain piece. I had a class on the element inside the string, but it was ignored. To fix it, I made the same class in the component where this was going on and made a :deep .myclass { @import "style" } rule where the nested import statement began to work. I didn't know the rules could be also nested like so.